# How i can delimite entity join level for JSON parse

Tags: json, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I'm new to web application development with **PHP, Symfony (Bundles) and Angular**

we develop a web application, works over **API rest building on symfony** and we make request through http protocol, every response is coded in **JSON**.

**Every JSON correspond to doctrine entity**.

We use **FosRest to parse entity to JSON**, here my config:

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format: json
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        xml:  false
        json: true
    templating_formats:
        html: false
format_listener:
    rules: ~
exception:
    codes:
        'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
        'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
    messages:
        'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
allowed_methods_listener: true
access_denied_listener:
    json: true
body_listener: true
service:
    inflector: app.util.inflector
```

Doctrine config

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_sqlsrv #pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
```

The generated JSON API is correct, here is an example

```
{
"id": 1,
"username": "admin",
"email": "admin@admin.com",
"enabled": true,
"last_login": "2016-07-04T16:31:07-0500",
"name": "admin",
"first_lastName": "admin",
"second_lastName": "admin",
"id_program": {
    "id": 1,
    "abbreviation": "LRI",
    "nomenclature": "LRI",
    "description": "Licenciatura en Relaciones Internacionales",
    "consecutive": "1",
    "cve_dgp": "3453454355",
    "first_period": "2016-06-09T10:30:00-0500",
    "campus": "HARVARD",
    "mod": "Escolarizado",
    "number": "863676476",
    "register_date": "2016-06-09T10:30:00-0500",
    "ref_number": "0976555",
    "require_pay": true,
    "colour_rgb": "253545454",
    "last_modification": "2016-06-17T12:51:28-0500",
    "id_level": {
        "id": 1,
        "cve": "LIC",
        "description": "Licenciatura",
        "last_modification": "2016-06-11T10:58:44-0500",
        "id_status": {
            "id": 1008,
            "value": "Inactivo",
            "active": true,
            "id_cat": {
                "id": 1004,
                "valur": "CatalogosEstatus",
                "active": true
            }
        }
    },
    "id_front_credenctial_file": {
        "id": 193,
        "name": "FRENTE-LRI.jpg",
        "extention": "jpeg",
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "md5": "e5643b567aa6e134ae1abcc23fdb545e",
        "is_perfil": false
    },
    "id_back_file_credential": {
        "id": 194,
        "name": "REVES-LRI.jpg",
        "extention": "jpeg",
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "md5": "d490d35f448d3fcb849cc708f7291bc5",
        "is_perfil": false
    },
    "id_status": {
        "id": 1007,
        "value": "Activo",
        "active": true,
        "id_cat": {
            "id": 1004,
            "value": "CatalogosEstatus",
            "active": true
        }
    }
},
"ldap": true,
"rolesdb": [{
    "id": 8,
    "id_rol": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "ADMINISTRADOR",
        "description": "Rol Administrador",
        "active": true
    }
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "id_rol": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "SHOWCASE",
        "description": "Rol showcase",
        "active": true
    }
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "id_rol": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "DESARROLLADOR",
        "description": "Rol desarrollador",
        "active": true
    }
}]}
```

The problem I have is when an entity has multiple relationships , as you can see in the JSON example , when parsing the entity being added all your relationships (**each key that starts with id_ is a mapped relationship with Doctrine**) and as our BD has grown considerably , there are times when a JSON has too much information that is hard to read from Angular side .

Is there a way to define (optimize ) until the parser level (JSON ) relations is made in an entity ?

or not include each join of the entity?

regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with @MaxDepth you can steer how deep you want to serialize your hierarchy and with @Groups you can manage which fields should be serialized.

Both can be set in your Serialization Context and are explained in more detail in the [FOS Rest Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/view_response_listener.html)

By that you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, but i found documentation only for JMSSerializer.

Do you have an example for FosRest?

will very helpfully for me. thanks

Comment: FOS Rest has no serizalizer itself, you'll have to install/config one, please check http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html#c-enable-a-serializer - which serializer are you using?

Comment: Actually, FosRest an symfony default, my configuration is described above. Thaks